# JFreechart SeriesException

Tags: exception, jfreechart

I am trying to plot a bar chart using timeseries by introducing the beginning and the end date , but i got a problem with the end date it indicate :
Exception in thread "main" `org.jfree.data.general.SeriesException`: You are attempting to add an observation for the time period 4-mai-2011 but the series already contains an observation for that time period. Duplicates are not permitted.  Try using the `addOrUpdate()` method.

```
final TimeSeries series2 = new TimeSeries("ip max", Day.class);

String datebegin = "04/29/2011 02:00:01";
String dateend = "05/04/2011 02:00:01";
DateFormat formatter;
Date date;
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
date = formatter.parse(datebegin);
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal1.setTime(date);
Date date2;
date2 = (Date) formatter.parse(dateend);
Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal2.setTime(date2);
while (((cal1.compareTo(cal2)) != 0))  {
    cal1.add(Calendar.HOUR, 24);
    String intermediatestringdate = formatter.format(cal1.getTime());
    System.out.println( intermediatestringdate);
    Date intermediatedate = (Date) formatter.parse(dateend);
    series2.add(new Day(intermediatedate),500);
}
```

Comment: Sorry Guys :$ it was just a matter of a variable mismatch

Comment: You can delete your question, or you can expand on your findings in an answer if you think others might benefit. See the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for details.

Comment: actually , instead of putting intermediatestringdate in tha date conversion command , i put dateend , since i've tried all i could do (after some searchs of course) i thought it was an api mis use, then i've add a lot of system.out.println i found the problem : Anyway this methode presents a way to set dynamicly a timeseries in jfree if there are some optim i'll be glad to get  them

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you are creating a time-based bar chart using [`ChartFactory.createXYBarChart()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html) with an [`IntervalXYDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/IntervalXYDataset.html), just construct the domain of your [`TimeSeries`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/TimeSeries.html) with a suitable [`TimePeriod`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/TimePeriod.html).

```
private static IntervalXYDataset createDataset() {
    TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Series");
    RegularTimePeriod day = new Day(29, 4, 2011);
    RegularTimePeriod end = new Day(4, 5, 2011);
    int i = 1;
    while (day.compareTo(end) < 1) {
        series.addOrUpdate(day, i++);
        day = day.next();
    }
    TimeSeriesCollection dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection();
    dataset.addSeries(series);
    return dataset;
}
```

Also, note that `Day.class` is no longer required by `TimeSeries`.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) it's a lot better this way :)

Comment: Excellent. Please consider accepting this answer by clicking on empty check-box on the left.

Answer (score 2):

If you change the TimeSeries and TimeSeriesCollection to be TimePeriodValues and TimePeriodValuesCollection, you will not have the unique time constraint to deal with.

here's what i did, and i'm able to plot time values along the x-axis that are identical down to the millisecond:

```
    TimePeriodValues data = new TimePeriodValues("duration"); 
    for(int x=0; x<_stats.getDataPoints().size();x++)
    {
        DataPoint dp = _stats.getDataPoints().get(x); 
        data.add(new Millisecond(dp._date),dp._duration); 
    }
    TimePeriodValuesCollection dataset = new TimePeriodValuesCollection(); 

    dataset.addSeries(data); 
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createScatterPlot("Title", "start time", "duration (millis)", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
    XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
    plot.setDomainAxis(new DateAxis()); 
    DateAxis domainAxis = (DateAxis)plot.getDomainAxis(); 
    domainAxis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")); 
    ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(new File(_reportFolder+File.separator+uuid+".png"), chart, 500, 300);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe here is the root cause of the problem. When adding list of time/value in the TimeSeries, the time point added must be unique from the whole list.

    series2.add(new Day(intermediatedate),500);

Otherwise, using addOrUpdate if there are possibilities of the time in the list.

    series2.addOrUpdate(new Day(intermediatedate),500);