# JFreeChart:I want to display some Category values..not all

Tags: jfreechart

I cannot write English very well, because I'm not a native.

My problem is this: I'm working to display a time series as a bar chart. I want a chart like the `XYBarChartDemo1.java` that combines aspects of `BarChart` and `XYPlot`. Especially, I want that the chart`s _x_-axis shows time using`Hour`, not`Year`. For example, the chart`s category has to show that value like 13:00, 14:00, 15:00 (at 1 hour intervals). How can I make that work?

Comment: Which of the [JFreeChart Samples](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html) is most like what you want?

Comment: Excellent. You can edit your question for clarification. See also the `JFreeChart` tag [info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jfreechart/info).

Comment: Wow!! Thank you for your attention.
I want a chart like the "XYBarChartDemo1.java".
It consists of the 'BarChart' and 'XYPlot'.

Especially I want that the chart`s x-Axis is time Axis.
...like 13:00, 14:00 ~ 15:00..not Year.

For example,
The chart`s category has to show that value..
...like 13:00, 14:00 ... 15:00...(1 hour interval)

And the chart has to have that value..
...like 13:00, 13:10, 13:20,...15:00...(10 minute interval)

Hmm. in short..
I want to hide the some category label.
or I want to show the special category label.

How can I do work? Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want [`ChartFactory.createXYBarChart()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#createXYBarChart%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20org.jfree.data.xy.IntervalXYDataset,%20org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean%29). For hourly data, use `Hour` for your `RegularTimePeriod`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6210074/230513) using `Day`.

Comment: It`s late. But I have remembered your help.

Comment: No problem; I'm glad you got it sorted out.